# If child button is disabled then stop passing event to parent

Tags: ios, uiresponder

I have a `UIButton` on `UITableViewCell` and if I set

```
button.enabled = false;
```

...then subsequent clicks on that button triggers click on `UITableViewCell`.

So if button is disabled then how to make sure click on it won't trigger table cell click?

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     if(!cell.btn.enable)
        return;
}
```

Comment: table cell should remain clickable. if button which is on cell is enable it's action sold get called and if it is disable nothing should happen. if user clicks anywhere else on cell, normal did select delegate should be called

Comment: like i said - that would be dealing with the event on a different level

Answer (score 0):

One way would be not to disable the button, but to just recognize that the button in question will not respond to touch events at the moment and do nothing
in the handler for this button.

```
if( buttonIsActive )
{
  // trigger whatever the button was intended to trigger
}
```

In order to do that you would need to subclass UIButton and add a property **buttonIsActive**.

If you don't do it that way, i guess you will have to deal with that event on a different level (like in the handler for the UITableViewCell) or turn of gesture recognition aka selection at all (see Praful Kadam's answer).